# Find Strings Located Between Specific Strings in List Python

Tags: python, string, list, substring

I'm writing code that's pulling in data from a website and it's printing out all the text between certain tags.  I am storing the result into a list every time the code pulls data from a tag so I have a list looking something like

```
Warning
Not
News
Legends
Name1
Name2
Name3
Pickle
Stop
Hello
```

I want to look into this list of strings and have code that'll find the keywords `legends` and `pickle` and print whatever strings are between them.

To elaborate in a further activity, I may create a whole list of all possible `legend names` and then, if they occur whenever I generate my list, to print those out that reoccur.  Any insight into any of these questions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
words = [
    "Warning", "Not", "News", "Legends", "Name1",
    "Name2", "Name3", "Pickle", "Stop", "Hello"
]
words_in_between = words[words.index("Legends") + 1:words.index("Pickle")]
print(words_in_between)
```

output:

```
['Name1', 'Name2', 'Name3']
```

This assumes that both `"Legends"` and `"Pickle"` are in the list exactly once.

Answer (score 2):

For the second approach, you could create a regex alternation of expected matching names, then use a list comprehension to generate a list of matches:

```py
tags = ['Warning', 'Not', 'News', 'Legends', 'Name1', 'Name2', 'Name3', 'Pickle', 'Stop', 'Hello']
names = ['Name1', 'Name2', 'Name3']
regex = r'^(?:' + r'|'.join(names) + r')$'
matches = [x for x in tags if re.search(regex, x)]
print(matches)  # ['Name1', 'Name2', 'Name3']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `list.index()` method to find the numerical index of an item within a list, and then use list slicing to return the items in your list between those two points:

```
your_list = ['Warning','Not','News','Legends','Name1','Name2','Name3','Pickle','Stop','Hello']
your_list[your_list.index('Legends')+1:your_list.index('Pickle')]
```

The caveat is that `.index()` returns only the index of the first occurrence of the given item, so if your list has two 'legends' items, you'll only return the first index.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `list.index()` to get the index of the first occurance of `legends` and `pickle`. Then you can use list `slicing` to get the elements in between

```
l = ['Warning','Not','News','Legends','Name1','Name2','Name3','Pickle','Stop','Hello']
l[l.index('Legends')+1 : l.index('Pickle')]
```

```
['Name1', 'Name2', 'Name3']
```

Answer (score 1):

numpys function where gives you all occurances of a given item. So first make the lsit a numpy array

```
my_array = numpy.array(["Warning","Not","News","Legends","Name1","Name2","Name3","Pickle","Stop","Hello","Legends","Name1","Name2","Name3","Pickle",])
```

From here on you can use methods of numpy:

```
legends = np.where(my_array == "Legends")
pickle = np.where(my_array == "Pickle")
```

concatinating for easier looping

```
stack = np.concatenate([legends, pickle], axis=0)
```

look for the values between legends and pickle

```
np.concatenate([my_list[stack[0, i] + 1:stack[1, i]] for i in range(stack.shape[0])] )
```

The result in my case is:

```
array(['Name1', 'Name2', 'Name3', 'Name1', 'Name2'], dtype='<U7')
```